# twilio application showing 404 error after deployment to Linux server

Tags: linux, proxy, connection-refused

We have developed a testing application in Twilio Sandbox and it is running fine in Heroku server. But when we are trying to put it in Linux (centos 8.1.1911) server, getting 404 error.

conf file in Linux server:

```
 location /myapp/ {      
       proxy_pass http://13.71.23.139:3020/;
       proxy_ssl_server_name on;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
```

error:
*212 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like maybe you haven't started your application?

Comment: Is the app running on `port 3020`?  Is the server `13.71.23.139` reachable?

Comment: @tink yes, both the server IP and Port are reachable.